# TestCafe - Storing results of Selector in variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

so in order to test, that my searchresults are different depending on the keywords I put, I want to store the nodelist of the searchResults before typing in a keyword and then compare them with the nodeList of the searchResults I get after adding a keyword, but I cannot get it to work.

I've tried:

```
let results = await Selector('#example')
```

However, this does not give me back a nodelist.
I also tried to just use a clientFunction with a `document.querySelectorAll()` but TestCafe then tells me to use Selector instead.

What to do? Is there maybe a better way to test this, that I don't see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract all the properties you need for later comparison.

Check this small example:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function removeSpanId3 () {
        const span = document.getElementById('id3');

        document.querySelector('div').removeChild(span);
    }
</script>
<button id="removeSpan" onclick="removeSpanId3()">Remove span</button>
<div>
    <span id="id1">
        test1
    </span>

    <span id="id2">
        test12
    </span>

    <span id="id3">
        test123
    </span>

    <span id="id4">
        none
    </span>
</div>
```

test.js:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `test`
    .page('http://localhost:8080');

test('Test1', async t => {
    const results       = await Selector('span');
    const resultsCount1 = await Selector('span').count;

    const result1 = [];
    const result2 = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < resultsCount1; i++) {
        const text = await results.nth(i).innerText;

        result1.push(text);
    }

    // Remove span
    await t.click(Selector('button').withText('Remove span'));

    const resultsCount2 = await Selector('span').count;

    for (let i = 0; i < resultsCount2; i++) {
        const text = await results.nth(i).innerText;

        result2.push(text);
    }

    await t
        .expect(result1.length).eql(result2.length + 1);
});
```